# XCode builds the last cource for ever while archiving

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I can't create archive for the project. XCode compiles all the sources and ends up building the last one for ever. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Sutuation is the same for 2 different projects with different teams, so it shouldn't be (I assume) a code signing issue.
I can build, run and debug projects on device.
XCode 7.3 (the latest one to date).

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: @sschale: Sure, I faced the issue several days ago and restarted computer and cleaned up the project many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a real XCode bug!
By commenting various parts of main.cpp (see the screenshot) a colleague of mine found the solution. Replacing the innocent code construction

```
if (gMsPerFrame > 66)
    gMsPerFrame = 66;
```

to

```
float newMsPerFrame = gMsPerFrame > 66 ? 66 : gMsPerFrame;
gMsPerFrame = newMsPerFrame;
```

made the trick.